# Is it possible to add values to context into a for loop?

Tags: python, django, list, view, detailview

I have a for loop to iterate a list.
In every iteration i have a different value, and i want to add this value to my context.
I'm trying using context.update, but every time this returns an empty context.

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Board_dets_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        id_board = self.object.id
        context['column_list'] = Column.object.filter(board_id=id_board)

        clist = Column.object.values_list('id', flat=True).filter(board_id=id_board)
        cCard = Card.object
        print(clist)
        for i in range(0, clist.count()):
            print('i=%s',i)

            cCard = Card.object.filter(column_id = clist[i])
            print('cCard=%s',cCard)
            context.update({'card_list': cCard})

        print(context)
        return context
```

cCard returns correct data.
The only thing I need is to store what come from cCard to context['card_list'], but evert attempt i made, was an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* filter that way. This will produce *n+1* queries, one for each `Column`. You can retrieve the last of `Card`s with:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Board_dets_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['column_list'] = Column.object.filter(board=self.object)
    context['card_list'] = Card.object.filter(column__board=self.object)
    print(context)
    return context
```

You can use two consecutive underscores (`__`) to look "through" relations like a `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`, etc.